# Document viewing according to permissions/login

Tags: web-part, list, permissions

We would like to see if there is a document library web-part that can have security based on specific users.

1. Say there are two doctors, Dr. Jay and Dr. Jack. We would like Dr. Jay and Dr. Jack to see access a particular document A than they
   should be able to do it. If we make a change to Document A then it
   should be the latest version that the doctors access.
2. Additionally, if we have a document B only for Dr. Jack and document
   C only for Dr Jay then they should each just see their personal
   documents.
3. This would be for authenticated users who login.

Answer (score 2):

- What do you mean by "external customers" - connecting to SharePoint requires either AD or a similar Form-based authentication configured (Claims - for SP2010, etc.)?
- Assuming that is done already, one way to achieve is by using OOTB Permissions (break inheritance) and configure SharePoint Groups with appropiate Permissions as follows:
- Visitors (Read Permission Level), Editors (Contributor Permission Level)

In addition, you could use OOTB features such as versioning. In Library Settings > Versioning enable settings as per screenshot.[image]

As result - Visitors will see only Major (1.0, 2.0) versions, while Contributors will also see Drafts (1.1, 1.2, 2.3,etc.) - e.g. Dr. Jay being Visitor only sees Major version, while Dr. Jack see also Drafts as Contributor.

Further down you could either create separate libraries with appropriate rights, or just break-inheritance on Folder or Document.